# Is it possible to move lines in a text file to another specific line?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I've been editing some text files recently, all of which are very similar and require the same type of editing. It's very time consuming to manually do these edits, so I started looking into C# to automate a good portion of it. I was able to figure out how to do some of the editing, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to code the most time consuming portion.

Is it possible to move all lines in a text file that start with a specific string, in this case "32,", and move them to a specific line in the text file, in this case line 70, after inserting a new line at the specified line? I have the code to select the files I want to do this too, I just can't figure out how to actually move the lines.

The code below does everything I want, except the output on line 70 is System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

```
foreach (string osuFilePath in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
        {
            string[] osuArray = File.ReadAllLines(osuFilePath);

            List<string> osuList = osuArray.ToList();

            List<string> osuStr = osuList.FindAll(s => s.StartsWith("32,"));

            osuList.RemoveAll(ss => ss.StartsWith("32,"));

            string osuString = osuStr.ToString();

            osuList.Insert(70, osuString);

            File.WriteAllLines(osuFilePath + "v2", osuList.ToArray());

        }
```

Comment: The answer to this is a definite "yes", but what have you tried so far? If you show us what you've done, then we can help fill in the blanks or suggest corrections.

Comment: @Kethsar If i am getting you correctly then you want to move the lines that start with "32" to another line in the same text file for eg. line 70.If this is the case then please reply and we'll try to do it for you ?,and if this is not the case please try to explain yourself using some examples and code you have tried to achieve this ?

Comment: @Aviral Yup, that's pretty much it. As for the code I've tried... I'll edit it into the main post now.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("MyFile.txt");
//List<string> lines2 = lines.ToList();

// manipulate here your array of lines

File.WriteAllLines("MyFile.txt", lines);
//File.WriteAllLines("MyFile.txt", lines2.ToArray());
```

The commented lines is if you prefer to use a `List<string>` instead of a `string[]`. It's normally easier to manipulate a `List<string>`.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously yes. The actual question should be "how?"...

For example:

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines("/file/path").ToList();

// change line position
String line = lines[3];
lines.RemoveAt(3);
lines.Insert(7, line);

File.WriteAllLines("/file/path", lines.ToArray());
```

(move the 4th line to 8th row)

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
string[] arrText;
string lineThreeHundred;

arrText = File.ReadAllLines("c:\test.txt");
lineThreeHundred = arrText[299];// choose line
```